# pm.process_idle_timeout under ondemand mode in php-fpm doesn't work

Tags: php, process, timeout, ondemand

I test ondemand mode in php-fpm. But pm.process_idle_timeout seems not working.
conf:

```
pm = ondemand

; Default Value: 10s
; pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s

; Only work with static and dynamic mode?
pm.max_children = 5

pm.max_requests = 2000
```

I send some trivial requests to respawn new processes. The children processes will be limited to max_children, but they will not be killed after pm.process_idle_timeout seconds. How does this mode work or is there anything wrong with my environment?

PS: nginx+php-fpm, php version is 5.6.22.

Comment: Please read tag explanations.  `python-idle` is for the IDLE GUI-based shell and editor.

Answer (score 1):

In your config you have:

```
; Default Value: 10s
; pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
```

The semi-colon (;) represents a comment. Remove the semi-colon and restart your fpm process.